# ssis sql task editor to create sheet and range

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, sql-insert

I have an SSIS package that contains a SQL task to create aN excel table once its been dropped, this works fine, my question is is it possible to either have a sql task to create a worksheet and a range. or a SQL task to insert data into a particular range within a previously created worksheet?